# Insert a symbol into array of *char type in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

According to my task I need to create a method of a class which allows me to insert symbol "+ " in string (in my case in *char array) after each five symbol of the string.

```
class String
{
private:
    char* st;
public:
    int length;
    int get_length(); //method for finding length of the string
    char* insert_plus();
};

char* String:: insert_plus()
{
    int i = 0,
    k = 0;
    int length_origin = get_length();

    while (get_length() < length_origin + k )
    {
        if (i % 5)
        {
            st.insert(i, '+');
            k++;
        }
    }
    return st;
}
```

I got an error in line

```
st.insert(i, '+');
```

I do understand that st is not a class, but I read on MSDN that this is the right way to insert a symbol. So please help me out how to do this right. 
Please don't be hard on me, I'm just learning.

Comment: Where did you read such thing? can you post a link? Maybe it was about `string` and not `char *`?

Comment: Bit more complicated than that in a char array. Probably the easiest way to do it is create a new array, larger than the first to hold the extra '+'s, and copy over five characters from the source array, place a plus, copy another five characters, etc... until done. Then delete the source array and replace it with the new one.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a string class yourself as a learning exercise, or you just want to use some strings? (In latter case just use `std::string`) If you want to create your own string, use `size_t` to store sizes.

Comment: Beside the problem you're asking about, i think u should review your whole logic: (1) your while loop doesn't run a single time (`length_origin` is equal to `get_length()`, and `k` is zero, so `get_length` can't be < `length_origin+0`). (2) And `0 modulo 5` beeing zero, your conditional code doesn't run, so since you never increment `i` you have an infinite loop doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `st` as a `string` class occurrence:

```
string st;
```

Now you can use the string class member functions such as `string::insert()`.
Then use `string::c_str()` to get the char* value of st for your return statement.

```
return st.c_str();
```

I haven't "spoken" c++ for a long time, check online docs for c_str eventual arguments.

Note: if not already included, don't forget to include the string class header file:

```
#include <string>
```